# Plpgsql function error at or near Create syntax

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error, plpgsql, stored-functions

I have just started using postgres and am new to the whole thing, I am using postgres version 9.6 and am trying to create a new function however I keep getting the error

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 6: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION time_passed(created text)
```

my function is this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION time_passed(created text)
  RETURNS text AS 

BEGIN

created :='Now';
RETURN created;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

What could be wrong with the Create syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the opening `$$` to match the closing ones:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION time_passed(created text)
RETURNS text AS $$
-- Here --------^
BEGIN
    created :='Now';
    RETURN created;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```